# Trying to make 2 docker containers talk each other

Tags: docker, mariadb, plesk

I have an ubuntu server running Mariadb 10.11 with Plesk and an app running on a docker container. The thing is that our app is not compatible with Mariadb 10.11 and the higher version that is compatible is 10.9. I was thinking to downgrade Mariadb from 10.11 to 10.9 but there is no safe way and i might end up setting up the server again. The other option, and more safe and correct i think is to use Mariadb 10.9 running also on Docker container and keep both versions. The thing is that i tryed to run Mariadb 10.9 in a docker container to serve my apps needs, the issue is that the main app that has to use that database is also running in a docker container in the same server and i am not able to find a way to make those two containers to communicate. No matter what i tryed to add in nginx directives to make them work, failed. Every help would ne appreciated!!!

Comment: Run both containers in the same docker network. Nginx directives can't make an app talk to a DB correctly (or are you using nginx as a TCP proxy between them - if so don't get the basic working first). BTW what incompatibilities exist in 10.11 but not 10.9 (now end of life)? MariaDB puts a reasonable effort into avoiding incompatibilies, where did they go wrong?

Comment: But the thing is that both containers in already on same network "bridge"... The problem that i am facing is that the app running on first container, runs on .net6 and the MySql.EntityFrameworkCore 7 is not compatible with Mariadb 10.11 and for now is not an option to upgrade .net in order to use MySql.EntityFrameworkCore beta 8 which is compatible with 10.11. The odd thing is that trying to access Mariadb running on the container from outside using server ip and mapped port (101.101.101.12:33061 for example) the connection is succefull. I dont get why the .net app in the container can't...

Comment: Alternate implementation https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector and migration  - https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/. Sorry I'm out of ideas on the container connectivity.